# Sign a file with certificate using Powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have a question, basically I have a file one txt and another one xml, I would like to sign those files with self signed certificate using Powershell.

Is there a way to do it?

My steps would be like that?

- First create a self signed certificate with powershell
- Then use that certificate in Powershell to sign the documents

Is that correct? 
Any idea how to do that?

After the document is signed do I have to provide to another party this self sigend certificate to be able to open the files right? Or how will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally, all my scripts are signed with an issued certificate, and it's my cmdlets to sign:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigningCert
Set-AuthenticodeSignature _path_to_my_script_ $cert -HashAlgorithm `
sha256 -TimestampServer "http://timestamp.digicert.com"
```

As to certificate, an issued one is recommended, rather than a self-signed one, it's not very expensive.

If you want to use a self-signed certificate, I think this cmdlet helps you:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -FriendlyName "My Cert" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -KeyUsageProperty Sign -KeyLength 2018 -KeyAlgorithm sha256 -Type CodeSigningCert -Subject "CN=System Error,e=mymail@mail.com"
```

I never created self-signed certificate on a personal computer, so this cmdlet is not verified. :(
If you have further questions, please let me know. :)

Comment: The term 'New-SelfSignedCertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Comment: And is it possible to to sign an XML file with it?

Comment: 1. To the unrecognized cmdlet, please check your PowerShell version and try to import the module `PKI` manually. 2. To the second one, I just took script file as an example, indeed you can sign any type of file.